# How to gather structural information of file?

Tags: excel, function

I am writing a function that eventually does store one of sheets from excel file.
I need to repeat this multiple times. I think I can use apply functions but then I need to check number of sheets in excel to use it is. 
Is there a function or way to check number of sheets (+ more information) of excel without opening the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe you have to open the file for a reference to the other workgook to work. The only way to do it without is to open a connection with the Excel ADODB provider and use an SQL query to gather your information, which is probably extreme overkill with what you need.